# How to read shell and insert in text (using Emacs)?

Tags: vim, emacs, vi

I want to read and insert output from shell (bash) in a text using Emacs.

My idea is to do something like `:r!ls` in **vi**, but using **emacs**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-u M-!` prompts for a shell command, and inserts the output into the current buffer.

If you want to filter a piece of text through a shell command, mark it and type `C-u M-|`.